# Powershell Script - Search AD and then restart service

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have created the below powershell script which looks at a local active directory, and searches for a particular string within the description field.

Once the script has found the particular computer name from the above search it starts the service in question.

```
$FullName =  "*Username*"
$LookUp = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description  -Like $FullName} -Properties Description | Select DNSHostName
$ComputerName = $LookUp
$ServiceName = "Service Name"
Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $ComputerName | Set-Service -Status Running
```

The issue I am having is that the Powershell script returns a 'service not found' message when I know (have manually checked) that the service exists?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the service start if you run only that line on the target machine?

ADDITION----------------------

I think you need to do this:

`$ComputerName = $LookUp.DNSHostname`

Comment: When specificing the computer name directly the powershell script works and starts the service.

Comment: Do this: `$ComputerName = $LookUp.DNSHostname`